# Is it better to code PHP locally or directly on server?

Tags: php

I have been having this debate with my boss for a long time, now I am having doubts about myself.

We work in a small team, with basically just me as a web developer and another assisting me when I need to do grunt work :P

My boss is trying to make me work on code that is directly on a test server, so he can check up on my progress...
I am insisting on working locally then uploading it when it's more stable, kinda like patches, because I don't want testers (my boss or sometimes even clients themselves) to see errors that are bound to happen while i am coding... and I save *very* frequently so working remotely means slower saves <_< which I find annoying.

So any opinions guys?

Comment: Even though this question is off topic here, I'm still not sure what you mean by "better", although I can relate to your problem. Obviously it's easier to write code locally and then push it to the server.

Comment: Indeed off-topic and also way too 'open'. There are no set rules for this, so there is no correct answer. This question could better be asked in the chatrooms.

Comment: The more important question is why does your boss need to check so often on your progress?  If a boss is micro-managing you that much it either means you've lost the confidence of the boss or the need to have results is going to cause many inelegant work arounds.

Comment: he never managed to make me work directly on the server, but he stills keeps bugging me about it.

Comment: to me, the problem comes down to me not completing things in time... because I personally believe I am overworked... 10-12hrs a day, for 5 days a week, and almost on-call on weekends to do 'quick fixes'...

Comment: You know 10-12h of coding each day won't work out on the long run? You're doomed to produce ugly code after a few hours of constant coding. Working overtime everyday will harm your code quality... extremely...

Comment: I wish that could be told to my company lol

Comment: Show this discussion to your boss... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its best to code on a development server (bascially local) and once you are finished with your code and tested it push it to the live/test server.

It's a very bad habit to develop directly on the live/test server as you are bound to get conflicts with other developers.

As you are working with another person you should also implement a revision control system. (Well basically even if you're developing solo you should. I also got one for my private projects as ist just makes it easier to revert mistakes.)

If you got a revision control system you can agree with all developers to only chek in changes that has sucessfully been tested locally and then create a commit hook that will update all commits to the testserver automatically.

So every time the revision is updated the test server follows while between commits the testserver stays stable.

Comment: I was the one who introduced the company to SVN... They objected to it, and still object to it because "it's too slow", or "why do you have to make it so complicated?"... There may be small projects we work on, but having sites either locally store on my own machine or on the server *only* and/or having my code and the server's not synced and/or someone touching the code without notifying me/another person coding in there, would cause soooo much trouble... but no, my boss shuts his ears to that and still complain that I deploy too slow, and he wants the test server updated once an hour...

Comment: You should probably switch the company. There is a massive need for developers these days you will easily find a better environment. - Revision Control is mandatory as is testing. Pushing to the test server on an hourly shedule regardless of the development cycle is irresponsible and will over the long run cause the projects to fail or get damaged.

Answer (score 0):

If its a private test site, it all comes down to what the client wants. I've worked both situations, and the latter does upset me more but sometimes that is what the client wants.

The (Client) want to double check every hour and then complain when something isn't even finished. Its not fun, I would ask him if you can move towards a local development, and push patches nightly or something.

Though the advantage of developing on a test server is you can notice problems that you might not notice until production. It has its up and downs. I usually develop locally and try and push my changes to an identical setup test server to check for any strange errors once a week.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work localy and periodically commit Your code to web-server. Some type of CVS must be installed on the server.

That so You can crash anything localy :), fast upload results to server and have 'undo' option in 1 click if something will not work on web-server correctly